# How to scroll up one line in terminal?

Tags: zsh

When I enter several lines command and the cursor is at the end of the last line. But I if I want to edit the last line command, how can I do it. For now I can only type <kbd>←</kbd> several times till I reach the beginning of the line and then move to the line above.

The command is like this:

```
➜  src git:(master) ./configure --with-features=huge \
>                   --enable-rubyinterp \
>                   --enable-pythoninterp \
>                   --enable-perlinterp \
>                   --enable-cscope
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Vim if it’s about your shell? Unless you have vi mode enabled in your shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using **Bash** or **zsh**, and you want to move the cursor inside the line itself, try <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> & <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>, and if you want to jump between commands, just try <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd>.

More shortcuts:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Home</kbd> take you to the beginning of the line.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> or <kbd>End</kbd> take you to the end of the line.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> take you left (back) one word.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> take you right (forward) one word.

More information here:
[The Keyboard Shortcuts for Bash](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/keyboard-shortcuts-for-bash-command-shell-for-ubuntu-debian-suse-redhat-linux-etc/)

Comment: That completely depends on which terminal you use. It doesn't work in any terminal that I use with Zsh. And Zsh definitely does not have those in its default keybindings.

Comment: OK. Weird that this is the accepted answer, when the question is tagged `zsh`.

Comment: I just tried it in Bash and I don't need to press Ctrl-Shift-Up/Down. Just Up/Down by itself works fine.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash, you can open up the command in a text editor with <kbd>CTRL-X</kbd><kbd>CTRL-E</kbd> so long as your `$EDITOR` environment variable is set. To set it you can `export EDITOR=vim` or put that in your `.bashrc`.

zsh do the same thing, but a keybinding needs to be [configured](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6620/how-to-edit-command-line-in-full-screen-editor-in-zsh).

Comment: I have already set `EDITOR`, but ctrl-x ctrl-e still don't works. By the way, my os is `mac os` and terminal is the default terminal.

Comment: You can also set (the more appropriate and correct) `$VISUAL`.

Comment: Works on Mac OS X with bash. Fails with zsh.

Comment: @DCMaxxx Yes, i am using zsh.

Comment: Then why is this tagged [tag:bash]? Grrr.